# $x\over(1-x)$ $y\over(1-y)$ $z\over(1-z)$ >= 8 when $x ,y ,z $ are positive proper fractions and $x+y+z = 2$

Tags: inequality

Q. Prove that $x\over(1-x)$ $y\over(1-y)$ $z\over(1-z)$ $\geq$ 8 when $x ,y ,z $ are positive proper fractions and $x+y+z = 2$

What I did: From A.M. G.M. inequality,

$(x+y+z)\over3$ $\geq$ $(xyz)^{1/3}$

or, $xyz \leq$ $8\over27$ (Putting $x+y+z = 2$ and cubing both sides) -----------1.

And, $(1-x)+(1-y)+(1-z)\over3 $$\geq [(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)]^{1/3}$

or, $1/3 \geq [(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)]^{1/3}$ (Putting $x+y+z = 2$)

or, $1\over(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)$ $\geq$ $1\over27$ ----------------------2.

But we cannot multiply 1. by 2. Since the inequality signes are different.

Am I missing something?

Comment: How to right Greater than or equal to properly?

Comment: $\geq $ is `\geq` inside mathjax.  Also if you write `x^{1/3}` you will get $x^{1/3}$ instead of $x^1/3$

Comment: what kind of numbers are $x,y,z$?

Comment: positive  proper fractions (I forgot to write the positive)

Comment: also $x>1,y>1,z>1$?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner No, they are Proper fractions, so less than 1

Comment: What does proper fractions mean? Are they rational numbers?

Comment: @BeniBogosel They are positive rational numbers (fractions between 0 and 1). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fraction_%28mathematics%29#Proper_and_improper_fractions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $1 = (x+y+z)/2$. The inequality becomes

$$  \frac{xyz}{(y+z-x)(x+z-y)(x+y-z)} \geq 1$$
which is equivalent to 
$$ xyz \geq (y+z-x)(x+z-y)(x+y-z)\  \ \  (1)$$
To see why this is true, apply AM-GM inequality three times:

$$ x = \frac{x+y-z+x+z-y}{2} \geq \sqrt{(x+y-z)(z+x-y)}$$
and the other two for $y,z$. Now multiply all three and you'll get $(1)$.